# Реализация verbose level в PHPUnit

Tags: юнит-тесты, php, phpunit

Предположим, что я тестирую с помощью PHPUnit какую-нибудь консольную команду с большим количеством вывода (например, чистильщика директорий, который выводит название каждого удаленного файла). Весь этот вывод мне может быть нужен, если я отлавливаю ошибки, но при общем подтверждении работоспособности его лучше спрятать - другими словами, мне нужно задавать тестам уровень детализации. Как это осуществить? Есть ли возможность опросить сам PHPUnit на наличие флага `--verbose`? `var_dump($argv)` сказал мне, что такой переменной нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас есть есть массив $_ENV. Если PHPUnit запускать с консоли, то можно в этот массив добавить свою переменную.  Логгер будет просто проверять ее значение и делать нужный уровень логгирования. С консоли запуск будет выглядеть так

```
VERBOSE=3 ./php_unit_script
```

VERBOSE - это имя переменной (я просто такое решил, Вы можете взять своё). Самое главное до и после знака равно не добавить пробелов.

**upd**

улучшу свой ответ. В php есть функция [ini_get](https://www.php.net/ini_get), которая умеет читать с php.ini параметры. А у PHPUnit запускалки есть параметр командной строки `-d`, То есть, можно запустить так `phpunit -d verbose=7`.